# Websocket is undefined immediately after receiving message in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, websocket

I'm using websocket in react. This is the code for the component:

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

export default function Component(props) {
  const [socket, setSocket] = useState();

  const parseMessage = (msg) => {
    if (msg[0] !== "R") sendMessage("123"); // ignore the very first message from the socket. 
  };

  const sendMessage = (msg) => socket.send(msg); // error at this line

  useEffect(() => {
    const socket = new WebSocket("wss://ws.ifelse.io/");
    socket.addEventListener("message", ({ data }) => {
      if (socket) parseMessage(data);
    });
    setSocket(socket);
  }, []);

  const sendMsg = () => {
    socket.send("test");
  };

  return <button onClick={() => sendMsg("clicked")}>send msg</button>;
}
```

I'm getting this error: `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'send')` at the marked line. The WebSocket is just an echo server, it sends back the same thing you send it.

If I wrap the `socket.send` in a try-catch block, I can still send and receive messages from the WebSocket using the button, but the error still occurs at that line in `sendMessage`.

It's clear that the socket variable is not undefined as I'm able to send and receive messages before and after the error occurs.

So my question is why is the socket variable undefined only for the brief period after receiving a message, and what is the fix for this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `useEffect` runs just once and in that moment the `socket` is still undefined. Function `sendMessage` references undefined `socket` when the effect runs. When the socket is set using `setSocket`, component will rerender, but the new instance of `sendMessage` (now referencing the existing socket) will never be used, because the effect will not run again.

It is better to use ref in this case.

```
export default function Component(props) {
  const socket = useRef();

  const sendMessage = (msg) => socket.current.send(msg); 

  useEffect(() => {
    socket.current = new WebSocket("wss://ws.ifelse.io/");
    socket.current.addEventListener("message", ({ data }) => {
      parseMessage(data);
    });
    return () => {
       ... release resources here
    }
  }, []);
  
  ...
}
```

Comment: Yep, that was the issue. I keep forgetting that functions are reinitialised on re-render.

Answer (score 4):

Better solution would be to initialize the socket outside

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

const socket = new WebSocket("wss://ws.ifelse.io/")

export default function Component(props) {
  const ws = useRef(socket)
  
  useEffect(() => {
    ws.current?.addEventListener("message", ({ data }) => {
      parseMessage(data);
    });
    return () => {
      ws.current?.removeAllListeners()
    }
  }, [])

  const parseMessage = (msg) => {
    if (msg[0] !== "R") sendMessage("123"); // ignore the very first message from the socket. 
  };

  const sendMessage = (msg) => ws.current?.send(msg);


  const sendMsg = () => {
    ws.current?.send("test");
  };

  return <button onClick={() => sendMsg("clicked")}>send msg</button>;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

When you use `useState` you create a state variable with an update state function. You also provide the initial value of the state variable in `useState(initialState)`.

In your case you are not passing anything (i.e. you are telling React it's `undefined`, that's why at this line:

```
  const sendMessage = (msg) => socket.send(msg); // error at this line
```

your code cannot use `socket.send` because socket is `undefined`.

Your `useEffect` runs after the return function and then the socket instance is created as well as set to socket state variable.

You need to make sure that you are only sending message over socket after socket is created.

For more on `useEffect` you can read this post:
https://jayendra.xyz/2019/06/17/how-useeffect-works/

Comment: I know this is not the case because I am able to send and receive messages on the socket between instances of the error message. In other words, I'm only sending the message after the socket is initialized.

Comment: Try putting this line: `const sendMessage = (msg) => socket.send(msg);` in an if condition. `if (socket) { const sendMessage = (msg) => socket.send(msg); } ` and check if you still get the same error.

Comment: No, I don't get that error if I check if socket is available.

Comment: I think that's the point. Even your error says that: `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'send')`. By the time when the `//error at line` code gets executed, socket is not available yet. You need to do this after socket gets initialised.

Comment: The error is happening after I send a message using the socket. So I think it's safe to assume that the socket is initialized by that time.

Answer (score -1):

You need to wait for the socket to be established first and then set the socket using setSocket in the `open` event. The way you are doing it now expects the first message to be sent by the server and then you setSocket, if the server does not send a message before you click on the button, the socket instance is not set in your state.
Do this instead:

```
socket.addEventListener('open', function (event) {
    setSocket(socket);
});
```

Here is the full code

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

export default function Component(props) {
  const [socket, setSocket] = useState();
  const [disabled, setButtonDisabled] = useState(true);

  const parseMessage = (msg) => {
    if (msg[0] !== "R") sendMessage("123"); // ignore the very first message from the socket. 
  };

  const sendMessage = (msg) => socket.send(msg); // error at this line

  useEffect(() => {
    const socket = new WebSocket("wss://ws.ifelse.io/");

    socket.addEventListener('open', function (event) {
     setSocket(socket);
     setButtonDisabled(false); 
    }); 

    socket.addEventListener("message", ({ data }) => {
      if (data) parseMessage(data);
    });

    return ()=>{
      socket.close();
    };
  }, []);

  const sendMsg = () => {
    if(socket) socket.send("test");
  };

  return <button disabled={disabled} onClick={() => sendMsg("clicked")}>send msg</button>;
}
```

Comment: Here is more info on WebSockets: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSocket

Comment: this has the same issue

Comment: also, why do i expect the first message to be sent by the server?